# Understanding AppRegistry.X()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, methods, native, static-methods

I am trying to understand [the official guide about AppRegistry here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/appregistry).

Could someone briefly explain what the following terms mean?

1. Headless Task
2. Registry
3. Runnable
4. Section
5. Config
6. Component Provider

Partial answers are acceptable.